# How to iterate through JSON data using an array for key values

Tags: javascript, json

Here is the JSON object:

```
{
  "stats":{
    "ie":{
      "9":"y",
      "10":"y",
      "11":"y"
    },
    "edge":{
      "12":"y",
      "13":"y",
      "14":"y"
    },
    "firefox":{
      "15":"y",
      "16":"y",
      "17":"y"
    }
 }
```

There is more data but this should give you an idea about the structure. This is my code:

```
var browsers = ["ie","edge","firefox"];

for (var i = 0; i < browsers.length; i++) {
  var bStats = result.stats.browsers[i];
  //Do something with it...
}
```

This gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. If I directly use `result.stats.ie` etc. everything works perfectly. How can I iterate through all this data properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't looking for the property `browser` which contains an array : `result.stats.browsers[i]` but for a variable property name, which can be accessed with square bracket notation:

`var bStats = result.stats[browsers[i]];`

The snippet below should demonstrate this in practice:

```js
var result = {
  "stats":{
    "ie":{
      "9":"y",
      "10":"y",
      "11":"y"
    },
    "edge":{
      "12":"y",
      "13":"y",
      "14":"y"
    },
    "firefox":{
      "15":"y",
      "16":"y",
      "17":"y"
    }
 }
 
 }
 
var browsers = ["ie","edge","firefox"];

for (var i = 0; i < browsers.length; i++) {
  var bStats = result.stats[browsers[i]];
  console.log(bStats);
}
```